# Excel random function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Excel problem:

- I have 9 different numbers or letters (from 1 to 9 or a to i).
- For each number I need to assign 1 number from remaining numbers (same number can not be assigned to itself for example 1 can not be assigned to 1).
- Second requirement is that each number has to be used only 1 time.

I already tried 1 example from here with modification:

`=IF(A1=A1, RANDBETWEEN(2, 9), RANDBETWEEN(2, 9))`

Unfortunately this does not work for me and I suppose 1 more IF needs to be used.

Can anyone help me with Excel code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update your question with your worked examples. Super User is not a script writing service. http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I tryied only randombetween function but I am not able to use it with if function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: what is not clear from explanation of problem? I am just unable to solve it by myself.

Comment: Sorry I already edited my question.

Comment: Homework (coursework)? Or explain please, what is the actual problem behind your question. There might be other solutions.

Comment: Not homework (coursework). I have 9 users. Each user needs to draw another user for christmas gift. Thats all :-).

Comment: @JanJesenius have you tried picking names out of a hat, or even googelin `random number generator in excel`

Comment: thanks for tips I want to have solution like I am asking. my task is not only about random numbers. there are 2 conditions...

Comment: You are looking to generate what's known in combinatorics as a derangement.

Comment: Please see https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50fx/home/combinatorics-using-excel-formulas-and-examples

Answer (score 0):

As there is no solution from anybody, I am sending one which works for me.
Maybe someone will need it in future.
However I am disappointed from answers to my question on this forum...

[image]

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptMJp.jpg)

Comment: +1 Bravo for working it out, you didn't need out help after all :) but -1, you need to understand we're not here to work things out for you, you need to bring more to the table. I hope this experience hasn't put you off using SU again in the future.

Comment: Interesting because I found similar question here and below were direct answers without commnets. This is the reason why I am disappointed.